# C++ character management

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am trying to create a program that will receive a 10-digit key and check if the characters 'c' and 'r' are included in it in specific place in the key, eg. : c in place 3 and r in 10 would accept keys like that: **c******r, where * could be any character, or letter or number. I 'come up to this point, but i cannot understan why i get erros with the pointers. I work on MSVS EXPRESS 10 for C++. Thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   char *code = new char[];
   char *ret1 = NULL;
   char *ret2 = NULL;
   int flag = 0;
   printf("                !!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("               !!      !!\n");
   printf("              !!        !!\n");
   printf("              !!        !!\n");
   printf("              !!        !!\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!               ####\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!  !!!!!!!   #############  #\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!  !!!!!!!   # #         ####\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!  !!!!!!!   # #\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("\n     This program is key-protected.\n");
   printf("  Please enter the 10-digit key to unlock:  ");
   do {
     std::cin >> code;
     if(std::strlen(code) == 10){
     ret1 = std::strchr(code, 'c');
     ret2 = std::strchr(code, 'r');
     std::cout << (char *) ret1;
     flag = 1;
   }
   else
     std::cout << "Wrong key. Try again:  ";
   } while(flag == 0);
   printf("\n                !!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("               !!      !!\n");
   printf("              !!        !!\n");
   printf("              !!        !!\n");
   printf("              !!        !!\n");
   printf("              !!\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   ####\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!#############  #\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!##!!!!!!!   ####\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!##!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
   printf("\n     Congratulations! You made it!");
   getchar();
}
```

Comment: Use `<string>` & `std::string`

Comment: `char *code = new char[];` - you need to specify the size of the array (`char *code = new char[11];` for example)

Comment: thank you all for your helpful comments and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your program is crashing because you haven't given size of the character array you want to create

```
char *code = new char[]
```

Correct way would have been

```
char *code = new char[11]
```

second thing you should notice that you are creating memory on the heap but you are not deleting it. Better approach would be to use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

I have corrected your code using std::string

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdio>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

       string code; // Using string type

       int flag = 0;
       printf("                !!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("               !!      !!\n");
       printf("              !!        !!\n");
       printf("              !!        !!\n");
       printf("              !!        !!\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!               ####\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!  !!!!!!!   #############  #\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!  !!!!!!!   # #         ####\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!  !!!!!!!   # #\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("\n     This program is key-protected.\n");
       printf("  Please enter the 10-digit key to unlock:  ");
       do {
         std::cin >> code; 
         if(code.length() == 10){
         size_t pos1 = code.find('c'); // If find function couldn't find character it will return string::npos
         size_t pos2 = code.find('r');

         if(pos1 != string::npos)
            std::cout << code[pos1];
        if(pos2 != string::npos)
            std::cout<<code[pos2];
         flag = 1;
       }
       else
         std::cout << "Wrong key. Try again:  ";
       } while(flag == 0);
       printf("\n                !!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("               !!      !!\n");
       printf("              !!        !!\n");
       printf("              !!        !!\n");
       printf("              !!        !!\n");
       printf("              !!\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   ####\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!#############  #\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!##!!!!!!!   ####\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!##!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
       printf("\n     Congratulations! You made it!");

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help! i encountered an erron at std::cin >> code; but i changed the line with getline(cin,code); and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the size of the char buffer `code` which you fill. To do it you should replace the line `char *code = new char[];` with `char code[11]` (static array). The size is 11 because C++ line always has the symbol of the end of line `'\0'`.

Also you can use `std::string` instead of `char*`. It helps to process strings without worrying about buffer sizes.